# Does convergence of operators imply convergence of kernels?

Tags: distribution-theory

Schwarz Kernel Theorem states that:

If $A: C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a linear continuous operator, then there exists a unique kernel $K\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\langle Au, v\rangle_{\mathcal{D}', \mathcal{D}} = \langle K, v\otimes u\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}$ for all $u, v\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My question is:

Suppose we have a sequence of linear continuous operators $A_n: C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with kernels $K_n$. And $A: C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is also continuous and linear with kernel $K$. If $A_nu \to Au$ in $\mathcal{D}'$ for every $u \in C_0^\infty$, can we conclude that $K_n \to K$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n)$?

By definition of kernels in the theorem, one can check that $K_n \to K$ when restricted on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So can we use a certain density argument to prove it?

Comment: What topology are you using on the space $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam the usual topology for the distribution space (I don’t how to describe this topology in a precise way)

Comment: The reason I ask is there is no "usual topology" for this space. The two most common ones are the weak-$\ast$ and the strong topology. However, it is my opinion that only the strong should be used especially in matters related to the nuclear theorem.

Comment: The distribution space is with the weak * topology. (And the test function space is with the topology induced by Fréchet spaces $\mathcal{D}_K$, and is complete) I use the definition in Rudin’s Functional Analysis.